# Javascript conditionals based on cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Im trying to set up some conditional statements that detect whether or not a cookie has been set when the page loads and applies some classes to a div based on the value of that cookie:

```
<script>
        $(function(){   
            if ($.cookie('view_size', 'large')) {
                $('#primary').removeClass('medium_content');
                $('#primary').addClass('large_content');
            };

            if ($.cookie('view_size', 'medium')) {
                $('#primary').removeClass('large_content');
                $('#primary').addClass('medium_content');
            };

            if ($.cookie('view_size', 'small')) {
                $('#primary').removeClass('large_content');
                $('#primary').removeClass('medium_content');
            };
        });
        </script>
```

I am using the jquery cookie plugin and I know the cookies are getting successfully set, so the issue must have to do with the way I have set up these conditional statements. Any ideas?

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing? Which conditions are passing? What value is in the cookie?

Comment: There is no behavior, no classes are being applied or removed. The cookie's name is 'view_size' and the possible values are: 'large', 'medium' and 'small'. The cookie values are being successfully stored and changed so the issue must be with the way this is set up.

Comment: First, try running with Firebug; you may see error messages, and you can set a breakpoint and see whether your code is being called at all.  Second, are you sure that the cookie is set when the page is first loaded?  This function will only be called once, when the page is loaded.

Comment: Ok so the error I am getting is: 

"$.cookie is not a function 
if ($.cookie('view_size')=='large') { "

But when I check the cookies in the page inspector, they are getting successfully set. Very mysterious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the syntax

```
$.cookie('view_size', 'large')
```

is the way that you create a cookie, and isn't meant to check the value of a cookie.  I believe you want

```
if ($.cookie('view_size')=='large')
```

Comment: Hmm still doesn't seem to be firing. Is the way I am initializing it correct? Should I add document.onload or something?

Comment: The $() wrapped around your function is jQuery shorthand for $(document).ready(), so that should be sufficient.